# Title of background music played in Snow's execution

Tags: the-hunger-games, music, music-identification

First music is there's a drum beat at the first 5 or 10 seconds of Snow's execution (if I'm not mistaken). While the drums are being played, Katniss walks slowly on the aisle.

[image]

Second is when Katniss stopped walking, the drums stopped too. Alma Coin gave her speech to Katniss. And the part when Katniss reaches her hands to her arrows, a music played. It's more like a voice of a girl? The voice of the girl can still be heard until Katniss shot her arrow to Coin.

[image]

### NOTE: I don't know if they are just one music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drums aren't part of the soundtrack. As to the part after the speech, it is actually called "[Snow's Execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games:_Mockingjay_%E2%80%93_Part_2#Score)". Here's the YouTube video:

Comment: Is it really entitled "Snow's execution"? Perhaps it is just the part when this music was played?

Comment: I'm positive it's called Snow's Execution. https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/hunger-games-mockingjay-pt-2-original-motion-picture/id1058134891 here's the official iTunes link. It's the 15th song on this.

Comment: yes it appeared on itunes! thanks for the help.